# C++ macro expansion in include directive

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer

In the current draft of the C++ standard (N4830, august 2019) there are the following paragraphs:

[cpp.include] p.2:

> A preprocessing directive of the form **#include < h-char-sequence > new-line** [...]

[cpp.include] p.3:

> A preprocessing directive of the form **# include " q-char-sequence " new-line** [...]

[cpp.include] p.4:

> A preprocessing directive of the form **# include pp-tokens new-line**
>   (that does not match one of the two previous forms) is permitted. The preprocessing tokens after include in the directive are processed just as in normal text (i.e., each identifier currently defined as a macro name is replaced by its replacement list of preprocessing tokens). **If the directive resulting after all replacements does not match one of the two previous forms, the behavior is undefined**. **The method by which a sequence of preprocessing tokens between a < and a > preprocessing token pair or a pair of " characters is combined into a single header name preprocessing token is implementation-defined**.

The sentence "*If the directive resulting after all replacements does not match one of the two previous forms, the behavior is undefined*" states that after the *macro expansion* is performed, the directive must match one of the two forms presented in the previous two paragraphs ([cpp.include]/2 and [cpp.include]/3). I will refer to this operation as **check**.

The following sentence "*The method by which a sequence of preprocessing tokens between a < and a > preprocessing token pair or a pair of " characters is combined into a single header name preprocessing token is implementation-defined*" implies that there is an implementation-defined process that transforms a sequence of preprocessing tokens between delimited by < > or by " " into a single preprocessing token (a *header-name*). I will refer to this operation as **process**.

My first question is whether **process** is only applied in the situation described in [cpp.include] p.4. I believe so, because *tokenization* is performed before processing of *preprocessing directives*, therefore in the first two forms of the *include directive* there is exactly one preprocessing token (a *header-name*) after "#include", not "a sequence of preprocessing tokens between a < and a > preprocessing token pair or a pair of " characters".

My second question is how is **check** performed? Is it performed before **process**? If so, is a sequence of preprocessing tokens separated by sequences of white-space characters (a white-space sequence can have zero or more white-space characters) compared to a sequence of characters by going lower in the "parsing hierarchy" (so that each preprocessing token in the first sequence is reverted to the characters forming it)?

For example the sequence of preprocessing tokens: `<io[space][space]stream[space]>` can be considered to match `< h-char-sequence >` if `<io[space][space]stream[space]>` is converted to the sequence of characters `[<][i][o][space][space][s][t][r][e][a][m][space][>]` (where [.] denotes an individual character)?

Considering that **check** is done first and it succeeds, then **transform** should be applied to the sequence of preprocessing tokens in order to transform it to a single preprocessing token (a *header-name*).

Are the details of these two operations and their ordering correct?

My last question is whether the last sentence in [cpp.include] p.4 is partly wrong. This is because it says: "[...] a sequence of preprocessing tokens between a < and a > preprocessing token pair or **a pair of " characters**". I do not think that the third form of the include directive can result (even after *macro expansion*) in a sequence of preprocessing tokens between a pair of " characters, because the " character alone is not a preprocessing token ([lex.pptoken] p.2) so I don't see any sequence of *preprocessing tokens* that can *expand* into "a sequence of preprocessing tokens between a pair of " characters".

Thank you.

Comment: Can you cite the specific draft you're looking at?

Comment: @HWalters http://eel.is/c++draft?

Comment: @HWalters I was looking at the current version of eel.is/c++draft, but the latest paper is N4830.